# no module named tktinter in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to install tkinter module because it was giving me no module error using:

conda install --yes Tkinter

but it did not work. how can I install the package in jupyter notebook ?

Comment: How do you plan on using a GUI framework within a notebook?

Comment: According to the description [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tk), it should be `conda install -c anaconda tk` instead.  I can't verify it because I don't use `anaconda`.

Comment: open both the terminal and jupyter notebook from same python interpreter env, then try installing using `pip install tk-tools`

Does this method work for you?

Comment: @IshanJ. `tk-tools` is not `tkinter` module, it is just a set of *custom tkinter widgets*.